# Circular gradient in android

Tags: android, gradient

I'm trying to make a gradient that emits from the middle of the screen in white, and turns to black as it moves toward the edges of the screen.

As I make a "normal" gradient like this, I have been experimenting with different shapes:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#E9E9E9" android:endColor="#D4D4D4"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

When using the "oval"-shape I at least got a round shape, but there were no gradient effect. How can I achieve this?'

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You can get a circular gradient using `android:type="radial"`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250dp"
        android:startColor="#E9E9E9" android:endColor="#D4D4D4" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Not only did it work, it also solved world starvation! Thanks!

Comment: Side note: It is also possible to use the transparency-byte in the color. #ff00ff00 to #7f0000ff will fade from fully-opaque red to semi-transparent blue.

Comment: android:gradientRadius="250" will be ignored. You should point to a dimen resource with a px or dp value, like: 
android:gradientRadius="@dimen/gradient_radius"

Comment: Thanks Bolling, you're right that the android:gradientRadius="250" doesn't work at all, I guess it behaved differently on older Android versions.

Answer (score 158):

I always find images helpful when learning a new concept, so this is a supplemental answer.

[image]

The `%p` means a percentage of the parent, that is, a percentage of the narrowest dimension of whatever view we set our drawable on. The images above were generated by changing the `gradientRadius` in this code

*my_gradient_drawable*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="10%p"
        android:startColor="#f6ee19"
        android:endColor="#115ede" />
</shape>
```

Which can be set on a view's `background` attribute like this

```
<View
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_gradient_drawable"/>
```

### Center

You can change the center of the radius with

```
android:centerX="0.2"
android:centerY="0.7"
```

where the decimals are fractions of the width and height for `x` and `y` respectively.

[image]

### Documentation

Here are some notes from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:gradientRadius) explaining things a little more.

> `android:gradientRadius`
>
> Radius of the gradient, used only with radial gradient. May be an
>   explicit dimension or a fractional value relative to the shape's
>   minimum dimension.
>
> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".
>
> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), and mm (millimeters).
>
> May be a fractional value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with either % or %p, such as "14.5%". The % suffix always means a
>   percentage of the base size; the optional %p suffix provides a size
>   relative to some parent container.

Comment: in kikat type radial will work when you remove %p from gradient radius

For Kikat
android:gradientRadius="10"

Comment: In API 21 you really need `android:gradientRadius="10%p"` (with `p`) or will get an exception. You can also set `android:centerX="20%"`.

Comment: @CoolMind, Would you mind editing the answer and updating it to reflect these changes? I'm doing more with Flutter now, so I haven't been keeping my Android answers up to date.

Comment: @Suragch, thanks for a detailed answer! I only wanted to say that you made a good job. Not every author can add all those attributes and describe what they mean.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it in code if you need more control, for example multiple colors and positioning. Here is my Kotlin snippet to create a drawable radial gradient:

```
object ShaderUtils {
    private class RadialShaderFactory(private val colors: IntArray, val positionX: Float,
                                      val positionY: Float, val size: Float): ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {

        override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int): Shader {
            return RadialGradient(
                    width * positionX,
                    height * positionY,
                    minOf(width, height) * size,
                    colors,
                    null,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
        }
    }

    fun radialGradientBackground(vararg colors: Int, positionX: Float = 0.5f, positionY: Float = 0.5f,
                                 size: Float = 1.0f): PaintDrawable {
        val radialGradientBackground = PaintDrawable()
        radialGradientBackground.shape = RectShape()
        radialGradientBackground.shaderFactory = RadialShaderFactory(colors, positionX, positionY, size)
        return radialGradientBackground
    }
}
```

Basic usage (but feel free to adjust with additional params):

```
view.background = ShaderUtils.radialGradientBackground(Color.TRANSPARENT, BLACK)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete xml with gradient, stoke & circular shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <!-- You can use gradient with below attributes-->
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <!-- You can omit below tag if you don't need stroke -->
   <stroke android:color="#3b91d7" android:width="5dp"/>

    <!-- Set the same value for both width and height to get a circular shape -->
    <size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp"/>


    <!--if you need only a single color filled shape-->
    <solid android:color="#e42828"/>


</shape>
```

Comment: Good example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/color1"
        android:gradientRadius="250dp"
        android:startColor="#8F15DA"
        android:type="radial" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:radius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should add android:centerColor

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:centerColor="#000000"
  android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

This example displays a horizontal gradient from white to black to white.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the solution. No matter that you want to make a radial gradient, do a horizontal one!

Answer (score 1):

```
<gradient
    android:centerColor="#c1c1c1"
    android:endColor="#4f4f4f"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:startColor="#c1c1c1"
    android:type="radial" >
</gradient>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/colorAccent_1"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent_2"
            android:endColor="@color/colorAccent_3"
            android:angle="45"
            />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
<color name="colorAccent_1">#6f64d6</color>
<color name="colorAccent_2">#7668F8</color>
<color name="colorAccent_3">#6F63FF</color>
```