# Shader as a drawable (Android)

Tags: android

How do I use obtain a drawable from a `Shader` (such as `LinearGradient`) so that I can use it as a background in my UI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the background will probably need to resize, we will use a `ShaderFactory` to produce the `Shader`:

```
ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf=new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        return new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
            new int[]{Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK},
            new float[]{0,0.5f,1}, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    }
};
```

We use this to create a `PaintDrawable` which we can use as a background:

```
PaintDrawable p=new PaintDrawable();
p.setShape(new RectShape());
p.setShaderFactory(sf);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(p);
```

This is just an example and in this case it would actually be better to just declare this [using XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html). Look at [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470072/circular-gradient-in-android).

Comment: how we can set angles like gradient drawable with using this?