# Android: Change center of linear GradientDrawable via code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

**EDIT: LOOK AT SOLUTION ABOVE**

i m freaking out. all i just want to do, is setting a linear GradientDrawable, which changes the vertical center of the gradient... drawing the gradient works fine, but how can i change the center of it?!?

```
RelativeLayout bgScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_screen);

GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
     GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
     new int[] {startColor,endColor});

gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
gd.setAlpha(200);
bgScreen.setBackground(gd); 


public void redrawOrChangeBackgroundGradient(){
    //??? either change center of existing
    gd.setGradientCenter(float x, float y) //ONLY works in RADIAL_GRADIENT or SWEEP_GRADIENT.

    //??? or complete redraw Gradient with different center

}
```

here s a picture example of how i want to change the gradient via code

[image]

cannot be that hard, can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lacking ability to set the center programmatically for linear `GradientDrawable`s is a [registered issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28482) already.

But there is a workaround [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762454/1140682). Basically, you should create a `PaintDrawable` from a [`LinearGradient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) and set it as your view's background drawable. Following this solution, you can set the center in your `LinearGradient` constructor by mapping the colors to the `positions` array:

> ***float[] positions***
>
> May be null. The relative positions [0..1] of each corresponding color
> in the colors array. If this is null, the colors are distributed
> evenly along the gradient line.

*(not tested, but it should do the trick for you)*

Comment: how we can set angle like gradient drawable with using this?