# Programmatically add Gradient with solid color and stroke

Tags: android, colors, drawable, gradient, shapes

Currently I am using this code to add color:

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
```

Now I need to apply some gradient colors to it along with stroke(like border with different color). I am setting this as background to button.

Here is what I am expecting, I need to do it programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add a [RadialGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html) to your `drawable` like this:

```
Shader shader = new RadialGradient(x, y, radius, color0, color1, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
drawable.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

Obviously, you can interchange [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html), [SweepGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient.html), and any of the parameters.

Here is how to add the stroke:

```
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
```

Hmmm, I think I have to defer to @StinePike with the [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html):

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.RED);
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
gd.setStroke(2, Color.WHITE);
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
```

Comment: Thanks what about stroke which i have it in my image? i mean the blue border

Comment: No buddy its not working and corners are rectangle now and also i want the stroke color to be different, can you please help me on that

Comment: That's all I got. When I saw your request I was expecting my RadialGradient example from a recent project to work for you. Without a bit of experimenting, I cannot help you any further. I hope this helped a little bit. Good luck!

Comment: One last and final question i tried this :GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN}); but i need the CENTER instead of TOP_BOTTOM

Answer (score 3):

use [GradientDrawable](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html&ei=9vZLUd3VMc3HrQei7YCQDA&usg=AFQjCNEgJapsy1ctT8WcuMTHCcuu2zb0UQ&sig2=j6exONYPFxkgO0pTkHtEAA&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk) to create gradient

or

you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381192/931982)

Comment: what about the stroke with color?

Comment: there is a setStroke method in gradient drawable

Comment: Yes its working now but how to make the gradient drawable with oval shape?

Comment: in the setShape method u can set OVAL as constant.. Please  check the whole gradientdrawable doc first

Comment: one question.. why dont you are creating the shape differently as xml and use it as background from code?

Comment: One last and final question i tried this :GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN}); but i need the CENTER instead of TOP_BOTTOM

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14383974/931982. if my answer solves your problem pls accept it.