# How to animate gradient?

Tags: android, animation, gradient, android-custom-view, ondraw

How to animate gradient from color#1 to color#2? Something similar to

[image]

I'm planning to use it as health-bar for unit (so, it will be finit animation starting with green and ending with red)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While googling it, I found 2 ways to do it for android: [use ShaderFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403101/lineargradient-center-animation) or extends View, using `new Shader(new LinearGradient())`. Both answers do the same - calling `new Shader()` every `View.onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method's call. Its really expensive if number of such animated gradients more than ~3.

So I did it another way. I avoided calling `new` every `onDraw()`, using single precalculated `LinearGradient`.  That's how it is look like (gif, so animation decayed) :

[image]

The trick is to create `LinearGradient` which is `colorsCount` times larger than `View.getWidth()`. After that you can use `canvas.translate()`, while drawing gradient, to change its color, so no `new` calls in `onDraw()` at all.

To create gradient, you need current width and height. I did it in `onSizeChanged()`. Also I set `Shader` here too.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    width = getWidth();
    height = getHeight();

    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(
            0, height / 2, width * colors.length - 1, height / 2,
            colors, null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    fillPaint.setShader(gradient);

    shapePath = getParallelogrammPath(width, height, sidesGap);
    shapeBorderPath = getParallelogrammPath(width, height, sidesGap);
}
```

I use path because of parallelogramy views, you can use whatever you want. When implementing drawing, you should notice 2 things: you need to `translate()` whole `canvas` on current offset and `offset()` your filling shape:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(-gradientOffset, 0);
    shapePath.offset(gradientOffset, 0f, tempPath);
    canvas.drawPath(tempPath, fillPaint);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawPath(shapeBorderPath, borderPaint);

    super.onDraw(canvas); // my View is FrameLayout, so need to call it after
}
```

Also you should use `canvas.save()` & `canvas.restore()`. It will save inner matrix of canvas to stack and restore it correspondingly.

So the last what you need to do is to animate `gradientOffset`. You can use everything you want like [ObjectAnimator (Property Animation)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property). I used [TimeAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator.html), because I needed to control `updateTick` and starting offset directly. Here is my realisation (a bit difficult and harsh):

```
static public final int LIFETIME_DEAFULT = 2300;
private long lifetime = LIFETIME_DEAFULT, updateTickMs = 25, timeElapsed = 0;
private long accumulatorMs = 0;
private float gradientOffset = 0f;

public void startGradientAnimation() {
    stopGradientAnimation();
    resolveTimeElapsed();

    final float gradientOffsetCoef = (float) (updateTickMs) / lifetime;
    final int colorsCount = this.colors.length - 1;
    gradientAnimation.setTimeListener(new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
            final long gradientWidth = width * colorsCount;
            if (totalTime > (lifetime - timeElapsed)) {
                animation.cancel();
                gradientOffset = gradientWidth;
                invalidate();
            } else {
                accumulatorMs += deltaTime;

                final long gradientOffsetsCount = accumulatorMs / updateTickMs;
                gradientOffset += (gradientOffsetsCount * gradientWidth) * gradientOffsetCoef;
                accumulatorMs %= updateTickMs;

                boolean gradientOffsetChanged = (gradientOffsetsCount > 0) ? true : false;
                if (gradientOffsetChanged) {
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    gradientAnimation.start();
}
```

The full `View` code you can find [here](https://github.com/Nexen23/I_am_here/blob/1.2.0/app/src/main/java/alex/imhere/fragment/view/UserLayout.java)

Comment: I don't understand ... you asked the question and answered it at the same time on the same day? This never was a question was it.

Comment: @Chris-Jr, I searched a lot and didn't find an answer I wanted. So I did some sort of research and finally got it. Then I thought "hm, maybe someone else will search it in the future and be stuck with it as I do?" - so I created the question with the answer. Also, there is a built-in feature to do that. Try to click `Ask Question`. There is a check `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style`

Comment: Ah, alright got you, I was just confused by the timing. Thanks for that, and thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: Thanks Nexen, it's definitely the right thing to do.  I appreciate it and I'm definitely glad to have your answer to start my own research from

Comment: thanks for point the way, time saved. Also TimeAnimator require api16, Objectanimator with AnimatorUpdateListener will also do the trick.

Answer (score 26):

I've figured out different, way shorter approach. Simply use `setColors (int[] colors)` method of `GradientDrawable` and animate it over time.

This is an example how to do it:

```
val start = Color.DKGRAY
val mid = Color.MAGENTA
val end = Color.BLUE

//content.background is set as a GradientDrawable in layout xml file 
val gradient = content.background as GradientDrawable

val evaluator = ArgbEvaluator()
val animator = TimeAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f)
animator.duration = 1500
animator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
animator.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
animator.addUpdateListener {
    val fraction = it.animatedFraction
    val newStart = evaluator.evaluate(fraction, start, end) as Int
    val newMid = evaluator.evaluate(fraction, mid, start) as Int
    val newEnd = evaluator.evaluate(fraction, end, mid) as Int

    gradient.colors = intArrayOf(newStart, newMid, newEnd)
}

animator.start()
```

And the outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

just rewrited @Krzysztof Misztal's answer to `java` :

```
public static void startAnimation(final int view, final Activity activity) {
        final int start = Color.parseColor("#FDB72B");
        final int mid = Color.parseColor("#88FDB72B");
        final int end = Color.TRANSPARENT;


        final ArgbEvaluator evaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
        View preloader = activity.findViewById(R.id.gradientPreloaderView);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable) preloader.getBackground();

        ValueAnimator animator = TimeAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
        animator.setDuration(500);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                Float fraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                int newStrat = (int) evaluator.evaluate(fraction, start, end);
                int newMid = (int) evaluator.evaluate(fraction, mid, start);
                int newEnd = (int) evaluator.evaluate(fraction, end, mid);
                int[] newArray = {newStrat, newMid, newEnd};
                gradient.setColors(newArray);
            }
        });

        animator.start();
    }




public static void stopAnimation(final int view, final Activity activity){

    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(activity.findViewById(view), "alpha", 0f).setDuration(125).start();
}
```

where the `view` is a simple `View` with gradient background:

```
//gradient_preloader
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FDB72B"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

the view :

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/gradientPreloaderView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/basic_8_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_preloader" />
```

hope my answer will help

Answer (score 3):

The up to date alternative answer.

```
class GradientAnimationDrawable(
  start: Int = Color.rgb(0, 143, 209),
  center: Int = Color.rgb(1, 106, 154),
  end: Int = Color.rgb(28, 179, 249),
  frameDuration: Int = 3000,
  enterFadeDuration: Int = 0,
  exitFadeDuration: Int = 3000
) : AnimationDrawable() {

  private val gradientStart = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, intArrayOf(start, center, end))
    .apply {
      shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
      gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT
    }

  private val gradientCenter = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, intArrayOf(center, end, start))
    .apply {
      shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
      gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT
    }

  private val gradientEnd = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, intArrayOf(end, start, center))
    .apply {
      shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
      gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT
    }

  init {
    addFrame(gradientStart, frameDuration)
    addFrame(gradientCenter, frameDuration)
    addFrame(gradientEnd, frameDuration)
    setEnterFadeDuration(enterFadeDuration)
    setExitFadeDuration(exitFadeDuration)
    isOneShot = false
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you write it in Java?