# Cannot set gradient as a circle background or src to an image view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient, circleimage

The gradient I have created it is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:dither="true"
        android:endColor="#00cff7"
        android:startColor="#0095bf" />
</shape>
```

In my XML file, I want this gradient to be visible as a circle.

I have tried the following but the gradient appears as a square.
I tried the following [third party library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) but the gradient is not visible.

XML

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_bg"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml/35287222) but still, the gradient is square.

Any help on how this can be achieved?

Note: I don't want the gradient to be created in a circular shape as I'm reusing it later in the app

Comment: Why not just have two drawables?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470072/circular-gradient-in-android

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? can you share screenshot?

Comment: check awesome-gradient for finding gradient as a circle background in android example https://github.com/cruisediary/awesome-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Use `CardView` like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="192dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You don't need `CircleImageView` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specified the shape :

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```